# How to improve execution time of the following Matlab code

Tags: matlab

Please help me to improve the following Matlab code to improve execution time.

Actually I want to make a random matrix (size `[8,12,10]`), and on every row, only have  integer values between `1` and `12`. I want the random matrix to have the sum of elements which has value (1,2,3,4) per column to equal `2`.

The following code will make things more clear, but it is very slow. 
Can anyone give me a suggestion??

```
clc
clear all
jum_kel=8
jum_bag=12
uk_pop=10

for ii=1:uk_pop;    
    for a=1:jum_kel
        krom(a,:,ii)=randperm(jum_bag); %batasan tidak boleh satu kelompok melakukan lebih dari satu aktivitas dalam satu waktu
    end
end

for ii=1:uk_pop;  
gab1(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==1)
gab2(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==2)
gab3(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==3)
gab4(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==4)
end

for jj=1:uk_pop;
     gabh1(:,:,jj)=numel(find(gab1(:,:,jj)~=2& gab1(:,:,jj)~=0))
     gabh2(:,:,jj)=numel(find(gab2(:,:,jj)~=2& gab2(:,:,jj)~=0))
     gabh3(:,:,jj)=numel(find(gab3(:,:,jj)~=2& gab3(:,:,jj)~=0))
     gabh4(:,:,jj)=numel(find(gab4(:,:,jj)~=2& gab4(:,:,jj)~=0))
end

for ii=1:uk_pop;
    tot(:,:,ii)=gabh1(:,:,ii)+gabh2(:,:,ii)+gabh3(:,:,ii)+gabh4(:,:,ii)
end

for ii=1:uk_pop;
    while tot(:,:,ii)~=0;
          for a=1:jum_kel
              krom(a,:,ii)=randperm(jum_bag); %batasan tidak boleh satu kelompok melakukan lebih dari satu aktivitas dalam satu waktu
          end
          gabb1 = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==1)
          gabb2 = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==2)
          gabb3 = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==3)
          gabb4 = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==4)

          gabbh1=numel(find(gabb1~=2& gabb1~=0));
          gabbh2=numel(find(gabb2~=2& gabb2~=0));
          gabbh3=numel(find(gabb3~=2& gabb3~=0));
          gabbh4=numel(find(gabb4~=2& gabb4~=0));

          tot(:,:,ii)=gabbh1+gabbh2+gabbh3+gabbh4;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general suggestions:

- Name variables in **English**. Give a short explanation if it is not immediately clear,
  what they are indented for. What is `jum_bag` for example? For me `uk_pop` is music style.
- Write comments in **English**, even if you develop source code only for yourself. 
  If you ever have to share your code with a foreigner, you will spend a lot of time 
  explaining or re-translating. I would like to know for example, what 
  `%batasan tidak boleh` means. Probably, you describe here that this is only a quick
  hack but that someone should really check this again, before going into production.

Specific to your code:

- Its really easy to confuse `gab1` with `gabh1` or `gabb1`.
- For me, `krom` is too similar to the built-in function `kron`. In fact, I first
  thought that you are computing lots of tensor products.
- `gab1 .. gab4` are probably best combined into an array or into a cell, e.g. you 
  could use

  ```
  gab = cell(1, 4);
  for ii = ...
      gab{1}(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==1);
      gab{2}(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==2);
      gab{3}(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==3);
      gab{4}(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==4);
  end
  ```

  The advantage is that you can re-write the comparsisons with another loop. 
  It also helps when computing `gabh1`, `gabb1` and `tot` later on.

  If you further introduce a variable like `highestNumberToCompare`, you only have to 
  make one change, when you certainly find out that its important to check, if the 
  elements are equal to 5 and 6, too.
- Add a semicolon at the end of every command. Having too much output is annoying and
  also slow.
- The `numel(find(gabb1 ~= 2 & gabb1 ~= 0))` is better expressed as
  `sum(gabb1(:) ~= 2 & gabb1(:) ~= 0)`. A `find` is not needed because you do not care 
  about the indices but only about the number of indices, which is equal to the number 
  of `true`'s.
- And of course: This code

  ```
  for ii=1:uk_pop
      gab1(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==1)
  end
  ```

  is **really, really** slow. In every iteration, you increase the size of the `gab1`
  array, which means that you have to i) allocate more memory, ii) copy the old matrix
  and iii) write the new row. This is **much** faster, if you set the size of the
  `gab1` array in front of the loop:

  ```
  gab1 = zeros(... final size ...);
  for ii=1:uk_pop
      gab1(:,:,ii) = sum(krom(:,:,ii)==1)
  end
  ```

  Probably, you should also re-think the size and shape of `gab1`. I don't think, you
  need a 3D array here, because `sum()` already reduces one dimension (if `krom` is
  3D the output of `sum()` is at most 2D).

  Probably, you can skip the loop at all and use a simple `sum(krom==1, 3)` instead. 
  However, in every case you should be really aware of the size and shape of your
  results.

**Edit inspired by [Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis):**

As Rody pointed out, the 'problem' with your code is that its highly unlikely (though
not impossible) that you create a matrix which fulfills your constraints by assigning
the numbers randomly. The code below creates a matrix `temp` with the following characteristics:

- The numbers `1 .. maxNumber` appear either twice per column or not at all.
- All rows are a random permutation of the numbers `1 .. B`, where `B` is equal to
  the length of a row (i.e. the number of columns).

Finally, the `temp` matrix is used to fill a 3D array called `result`. I hope, you can adapt it to your needs.

```
clear all;
A = 8; B = 12; C = 10;
% The numbers [1 .. maxNumber] have to appear exactly twice in a
% column or not at all.
maxNumber = 4;
result = zeros(A, B, C);
for ii = 1 : C
    temp = zeros(A, B);
    for number = 1 : maxNumber
        forbiddenRows = zeros(1, A);
        forbiddenColumns = zeros(1, A/2);
        for count = 1 : A/2
            illegalIndices = true;
            while illegalIndices
                illegalIndices = false;
                % Draw a column which has not been used for this number.
                randomColumn = randi(B);
                while any(ismember(forbiddenColumns, randomColumn))
                    randomColumn = randi(B);
                end
                % Draw two rows which have not been used for this number.
                randomRows = randi(A, 1, 2);
                while randomRows(1) == randomRows(2)  ...
                      || any(ismember(forbiddenRows, randomRows))
                  randomRows = randi(A, 1, 2);
                end
                % Make sure not to overwrite previous non-zeros.
                if any(temp(randomRows, randomColumn))
                    illegalIndices = true;
                    continue;
                end
            end
            % Mark the rows and column as forbidden for this number.
            forbiddenColumns(count) = randomColumn;
            forbiddenRows((count - 1) * 2 + (1:2)) = randomRows;
            temp(randomRows, randomColumn) = number;
        end
    end

    % Now every row contains the numbers [1 .. maxNumber] by 
    % construction. Fill the zeros with a permutation of the
    % interval [maxNumber + 1 .. B].
    for count = 1 : A
        mask = temp(count, :) == 0;
        temp(count, mask) = maxNumber + randperm(B - maxNumber);
    end

    % Store this page.
    result(:,:,ii) = temp;
end
```

Comment: wow, so fast...thanks for your code mr...it is useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the code below will improve the timing significantly. It's not perfect yet, it can all be optimized a lot further.

But, before I do so: I think what you want is fundamentally impossible.

So you want

- all rows contain the numbers 1 through 12, in a random permutation
- any value between 1 and 4 must be present either twice or not at all in any column

I have a hunch this is **impossible** (that's why your code *never* completes), but let me think about this a bit more.

Anyway, my 5-minute-and-obvious-improvements-only-version:

```
clc
clear all

jum_kel  =  8;
jum_bag  =  12;
uk_pop   =  10;

A = jum_kel; % renamed to make language independent 
B = jum_bag; % and a lot shorter for readability
C = uk_pop;

krom = zeros(A, B, C);
for ii = 1:C;
    for a = 1:A
        krom(a,:,ii) = randperm(B);
    end
end

gab1  = sum(krom == 1);
gab2  = sum(krom == 2);
gab3  = sum(krom == 3);
gab4  = sum(krom == 4);

gabh1 = sum( gab1 ~= 2 & gab1 ~= 0 );
gabh2 = sum( gab2 ~= 2 & gab2 ~= 0 );
gabh3 = sum( gab3 ~= 2 & gab3 ~= 0 );
gabh4 = sum( gab4 ~= 2 & gab4 ~= 0 );

tot   = gabh1+gabh2+gabh3+gabh4;


for ii = 1:C
    ii
    while tot(:,:,ii) ~= 0

        for a = 1:A
            krom(a,:,ii) = randperm(B);
        end

        gabb1  =  sum(krom(:,:,ii) == 1);
        gabb2  =  sum(krom(:,:,ii) == 2);
        gabb3  =  sum(krom(:,:,ii) == 3);
        gabb4  =  sum(krom(:,:,ii) == 4);

        gabbh1 = sum(gabb1 ~= 2 & gabb1 ~= 0)
        gabbh2 = sum(gabb2 ~= 2 & gabb2 ~= 0);
        gabbh3 = sum(gabb3 ~= 2 & gabb3 ~= 0);
        gabbh4 = sum(gabb4 ~= 2 & gabb4 ~= 0);

        tot(:,:,ii) = gabbh1+gabbh2+gabbh3+gabbh4;

    end
end
```

Comment: I think so, it's imposible to do. but when I tried to be used only for value "1". it was work fast. hahaha so i think, it is still have chance to solve right.

Comment: but I have to do make this matrix. Maybe you know another suggestion code mr. and of course it is faster than current code. because i just know code like this to make matrix like what i want.